# Skype button not showing after re-routing

Tags: angular, skype, skypedeveloper

I am trying to build a webapp with angular in which I want people to see the skype button of the skype web control on a certain route. But for some reason, the button isn't there after that route becomes active. For some reason the chat button isn't available after redirecting from the homepage but is there when I open that route directly. Please help me solve this problem. I've added two screenshots regarding these two cases.
[Chat button not showing after being routed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwFA6.png)

[Chat button showing after directly entering the route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDcJV.png)

This is my `app-routing.module.ts` file:

```
import { DoComponent } from './do/do.component';
import { CoComponent } from './co/co.component';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [{
  path: 'co',
  component: CoComponent,
},
{
  path: 'do',
  component: DoComponent,
},
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

This is my `app.component.html` file:

```
<div [routerLink]="dir">Click me</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

This is my `app.component.ts` file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'dem';
  dir = "do"

  ngOnInit(){
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.dir = "do"
    }, 10000);
  }
}
```

This is my `do.component.html` file contents:

```
<div class="skype-button bubble" data-contact-id="live:vabs.here1"></div>
```

Comment: Can you please share code snippets.

Comment: @PrathmeshDali added!